# Using javascript's indexOf on an array of svg text elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, svg, indexof

I am working with an svg file which has a number of text elements within it.  The text elements are all numbers.  I am able to get the list of values and put them into an array with the following line of code.

```
var fretdata = document.getElementById("fretinformation").getElementsByTagName("text");
```

I am able to access `.length` property and also the access the array elements by index such as `[0].textContent`.  However, when I try to use the `.indexOf()` function on the array, I receive an error message that the object (my array) does not support the property or method of indexOf.

I am able to setup a for loop to iterate through the array checking each value looking for the presence or absence of a certain value.  I would like something with the simplicity of the indexOf functionality which tells me whether or not something is present within the array and where it is if present.  Is there a to get `.indexOf()` working with the svg text element array?  Or is there a similar alternative which does not require the use of loops and flags?

I think the problem lies in the fact that I have an array of text elements and not an array of strings.  But I'm not sure how to directly get the array of the text element's `textContent`

```
var fretdata = document.getElementById("fretinformation").getElementsByTagName("text");
  //var fretdata = document.getElementById("fretinformation").getElementsByTagName("text").textcontent;

  //18th fret is the upper fret limit
  //0 fret (open string) is the lower fret limit

  //var zerolocation=fretdata.indexOf("0");
for (fd=0;fd<fretdata.length;fd++){
      if(fretdata[fd].textContent=="0"){
          document.getElementById("downkey").setAttribute("onclick",null);
          document.getElementById("downkey").getElementsByTagName("polygon")[0].style.fill="#D3D3D3";
      }
}
```

Iterating in the loop works.  The two lines commented out using the .indexOf do not.
Thanks, --christopher

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterating the elements is really an option, but if you don't like it, you may have 2 more options depending on your setup:

The following code requires `map` function (check [compatibility here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Browser_compatibility), it basically requires IE9+) and slice function compatibility (same, IE9+).

```
var fretdata = document.getElementById("fretinformation").getElementsByTagName("text");
alert([].slice.call(fretdata).map(function(o) { return o.textContent; }).indexOf("1"));
```

The other one requires jQuery, it handles a lot of stuff for you.

```
alert($( "#fretinformation > text" ).filter(function() { return $(this).text() === "1"; } ).length);
```

Answer (score 2):

What you have is not an array, it's a [**nodeList**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList).

A nodeList has `length`, and is array-like, but array methods like `indexOf`, `forEach` etc. doesn't work on nodeLists.

You can convert a nodeList to an array like this

```
var array = Array.prototype.slice.call(fretdata);
```

but in your case you really shouldn't, you should stick to the iteration instead.

Comment: Thanks.  I ended up iterating through once and pushed each textContent value into an array so that I could use indexOf to easily determine if a value was not in the array.

Answer (score 0):

use ES6 spread operators

```
var fretdata = [...(document.getElementById("fretinformation").getElementsByTagName("text"))]
```

This internally works as

```
var array = Array.prototype.slice.call(fretdata);
```